# Detect if make command target is a path or a phony

Tags: makefile

#### Background

I am writing several books in Markdown. My files are structured as follows:

```
                                       Description
writing/
    Makefile                        1. main Makefile (shown below)
    book.template                   2. pandoc template that uses TITLE
    books/
        current.txt                 3. contains the current book name
        book1/
            meta.mk                 4. sub-Makefile that defines TITLE
            chapters/
                01.md               5. actual text of book 1, chapter 1
                02.md
                ...
        book2/
            meta.mk
            chapters/
                01.md
                02.md
                ...
        ...
```

Here is the Makefile:

```
CURR_BOOK_NAME:=$(shell cat books/current.txt)
CURR_BOOK_DIR:=books/$(CURR_BOOK_NAME)/
CURR_CHAPTERS_DIR:=$(CURR_BOOK_DIR)chapters/
CURR_CHAPTERS:=$(wildcard $(CURR_CHAPTERS_DIR)*.pdf)

# suppose that each meta.mk defines the TITLE variable
include $(CURR_BOOK_DIR)/meta.mk


all: pdfs
    ...

pdfs: $(CURR_CHAPTERS)

%.pdf: %.md book.template
    pandoc -o $@ $< ...           \
        --template=book.template  \
        --variable=title:$(TITLE)
```

I usually work on only one book at a time. Thus, it was convenient to create a file `current.txt` with the name of the current book. Now I just type `make` to compile the current book to PDF by having the Makefile read in `current.txt`. Note that the PDF depends on a variable defined in the book-specific `meta.mk`.

#### Question

Occasionally, I want to make a small change to another book. How should I modify the Makefile so that I don’t have to update `current.txt` and then change it back each time? To be more precise, I would like to detect whether the arguments passed to `make` on the command line are phony targets or paths. For example, I would like the process to look like:

```
$ cat books/current.txt
book1
$ ls books/*/chapters/*
books/book1/chapters/01.md  books/book1/chapters/02.md
books/book2/chapters/01.md  books/book2/chapters/02.md

$ make
pandoc -o books/book1/chapters/01.pdf ... --variable=title:One
pandoc -o books/book1/chapters/02.pdf ... --variable=title:One
$ ls books/*/chapters/*
books/book1/chapters/01.md  books/book1/chapters/02.md
books/book1/chapters/01.pdf books/book1/chapters/02.pdf
books/book2/chapters/01.md  books/book2/chapters/02.md

$ make books/book2/chapters/01.pdf
pandoc -o books/book2/chapters/01.pdf ... --variable=title:Two
$ ls books/*/chapters/*
books/book1/chapters/01.md  books/book1/chapters/02.md
books/book1/chapters/01.pdf books/book1/chapters/02.pdf
books/book2/chapters/01.md  books/book2/chapters/02.md
books/book2/chapters/01.pdf
```

#### Possible solutions

It was suggested to override the variable on the command line:

```
make CURR_BOOK_NAME=book2 books/book2/chapters/01.pdf
```

However, I think this is too verbose and redundant, since it requires repeating the name of the book twice, and typing the name of the internal variable `CURR_BOOK_NAME` once.

#### Note

This is a simplified example. Please ask if you want to see the actual Makefile. Also, feel free to clarify the question title.

Answer (score 1):

The following valuable answer was posted earlier, but after a short discussion of pros/cons in the comments, the answerer deleted it and left a downvote without opting to comment. I [reproduce](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285960/is-it-appropriate-to-rescue-good-code-from-a-self-deleted-answer/) it here in case it helps other users. I am still looking for a “more complicated” solution that avoids the redundancy and allows building individual chapters.

---

A simple solution would be copy your `Makefile` to a new file, say `book.mak` and delete the first line `CURR_BOOK_NAME:=$(shell cat books/current.txt)`. Then create new Makefile like this:

```
CURR_BOOK_NAME:=$(shell cat books/current.txt)

current:
    $(MAKE) -f book.mak CURR_BOOK_NAME="$(CURR_BOOK_NAME)"

book1:
    $(MAKE) -f book.mak CURR_BOOK_NAME="book1"

book2:
    $(MAKE) -f book.mak CURR_BOOK_NAME="book2"
```

Then when you change something in book1 while book2 is current just type `make book1`. The makefile will figure out what's changed and update it.

If you really want to be able to type `make books/book2/chapters/01.pdf` then it's a fair bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure this so that your top-level Makefile is referenced from the top-level directory of each individual project. Think of it as a support library for each book project and manage it accordingly.

The individual Makefile can then be as simple as

```
include /usr/local/share/lib/bookmaker/main.mk
```

... assuming you call the library `bookmaker` and install it at this path. (It could live in a tree somewhere below your home directory just as well.)

I would think of this as a normalization of your de facto project structure, more than a new arrangement. Your individual books already  depend on the bookmaker Makefile, but forcing them to live in physical subdirectories makes it harder to work on an experimental clone (assuming you manage each individual book as a separate Git project -- if not, switching to this model probably makes even more sense!). You can also get rid of the  minor but pesky inconvenience of the "current" state file you will now obviously no longer need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can’t upvote it, as of one hour ago. I suppose I was reluctant to create one-line Makefiles in each book directory, since it seemed redundant. I was trying to parse `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` instead.

Comment: ThIs arrangement also allows you to get rid of `meta.mk` since it can now be refactored into the book's main Makefile; so you already have a one-line file in each directory. But this one is somewhat more general (though of course, the meta file could just as well define additional targets or override rules from the main Makefile, albeit more obscurely).